# Unit test to to alert me if len(X) - len(pred_values) != num_step

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I am not that good with "unittest" topic. I'd liked to create a unit test in  order to say "Hey body, this is the wrong (or right) answer because blabla!". I need to place a unit test because it took 3 MF weeks to find why the prediction did not work! Hence I want to avoid that type of error in the future.

**Questions :**

1. How can I ask the code to alert me when `len(X) - len(pred_values)` is not equal to `num_step`?
2. Do I need to create a unit test file to gather all the unit tests, e.g. `unittest.py`?
3. Do we need to place the unit tests away from the main code?

Comment: It sounds like order of test execution is important? That's an anti patten under most circumstances. Why do you want to execute tests in a specific order? If I've got the wrong I please rephrase the question.

Comment: Can you be clearer on your question please. Add context. E.g., "prediction" makes me think you're doing machine learning?

Comment: Yes indeed, this is a machine learning problem but in the backtesting phase.

Comment: Do you simply want to know how to test that `len(X) - len(pred_values) ==num_steps` is True?

Comment: I have many unit test to place, so I think it might be right to place all of those in a python file. I don't want a boolean statement. I just want to tell me when that statement appear.

Answer (score 1):

[Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/talks.html) is fantastic for unit tests. Has great community behind it, lots of documentation, and a compelling number of libraries that will simplify your unit testing life.

```
pip install pytest
```

Create a folder called tests. In that add `__init__.py` and a file called test_thing.py then add:

```
def test_foo():
    assert len(X) - len(pred_values) ==num_steps
```

Then run `pytest .`

Comment: Can you make an example how I can code it inside unittest.py and how I can use it inside anotherfile.py? It's been two months I am working with python. So it could be nice to have someone to teach me about unittest in that particular case.

Comment: The documentation and the link above is much clearer than a comments on here.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but really you will need to read the documentation. You will need to know about installing pytest, gotchas, helpful libraries, fact it uses dependency injection and more

Comment: What is gotchas? Can you send me a link? Or maybe English is not my first language and I look stupid right now :P

Comment: "gotcha" is an British idiom meaning "a common error the uninitiated can encounter". Don't sweat. I'm sure your English is better than my ability to speak your language 

Comment: Do I need to integrate it to anotherfile.py where the real code is located or I need to always separate the real code from the unittest code?

Comment: Spoonfeeding this is ineffective. Please read the documentation.